# Post navigation block with [shortcode]

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I’m trying to create a post navigation (previous/next posts) shortcode to use it in the block editor in the middle of the body. The block should include thumbnails as well.

This is what I tried in the functions.php:

```
function wpb_posts_nav(){
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    $prev_post = get_previous_post();
     
    if ( $next_post || $prev_post ) : ?>
     
        <div class="wpb-posts-nav">
            <div>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $prev_post ) ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post ); ?>">
                        <div>
                            <div class="wpb-posts-nav__thumbnail wpb-posts-nav__prev">
                                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $prev_post, [ 100, 100 ] ); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <strong>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path d="M13.775,18.707,8.482,13.414a2,2,0,0,1,0-2.828l5.293-5.293,1.414,1.414L9.9,12l5.293,5.293Z"/></svg>
                                <?php _e( 'Previous article', 'textdomain' ) ?>
                            </strong>
                            <h4><?php echo get_the_title( $prev_post ); ?></h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $next_post ) ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post ); ?>">
                        <div>
                            <strong>
                                <?php _e( 'Next article', 'textdomain' ) ?>
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24"><path d="M10.811,18.707,9.4,17.293,14.689,12,9.4,6.707l1.415-1.414L16.1,10.586a2,2,0,0,1,0,2.828Z"/></svg>
                            </strong>
                            <h4><?php echo get_the_title( $next_post ); ?></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="wpb-posts-nav__thumbnail wpb-posts-nav__next">
                                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $next_post, [ 100, 100 ] ); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- .wpb-posts-nav -->
     
    <?php endif;
}
add_shortcode( ‘custom-post-nav’, ‘wpb_posts_nav’ );
```

and this is the css:

```
.wpb-posts-nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
 
.wpb-posts-nav a {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    align-items: center;
}
 
.wpb-posts-nav h4,
.wpb-posts-nav strong {
    margin: 0;
}
 
.wpb-posts-nav a svg {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
 
.wpb-posts-nav > div:nth-child(1) a {
    grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
    text-align: left;
}
 
.wpb-posts-nav > div:nth-child(2) a {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 100px;
    text-align: right;
}
 
.wpb-posts-nav__thumbnail {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
 
.wpb-posts-nav__thumbnail img {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

But then if try to use the [custom-post-nav] shortcode in the block editor, I get an JSON error and I can't publish my post. The css-style seems to be okay, because if I use the code at the bottom of the post, it appears and looks good. But it appears at the wrong place (at the top of the page). And I cannot use the code anywhere else because then I get the error.

Any help is appreciated. Maybe someone knows what I'm missing. Thanks!